# How to start, where to start MScharts?

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I want to learn MSCharts in asp.net. Please suggest some good and easy online resources for learning MSCharts.

Thanks in advance.

Vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download `MSChart.exe` from 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14422

and to learn visit
 http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Answer (score 0):

There is a product detailed here http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart, that includes hundreds of samples, and the support code behind them.  This is how i acclimated myself to the controls.